# Upload error: Do not have last keystore for Android app

Tags: android

An app is built by another developer they don't have a key file. I know there is no way to get back key store. This is the error message shown to me when I updating old APK to new APK:

[image]

Is it possible to unpublish old app and republish the new app with the same package name, version code, and version name?

I want to known that the users will get an update for the app or not. Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I will keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have the keystore that was originally used to upload the application, you cannot publish an update to that application.

Your only option if you do not have the correct keystore is to publish the application as a completely new app in the Play Store with a new app id. Your users will need to download the new application independently of the old app.

Comment: If unpublish old one and publish it as a new app then I use same package name or I have to change it.

Comment: You will have to change it.